# How to use SEXTANTE in a script outside QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, geoprocessing, pyqgis, sextante

I´m trying to do some geoprocessing using the QGIS Sextante plugin outside of the QGIS application (and integrate it with different other libraries like arcpy, etc.).

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
QApplication(sys.argv)
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

sys.path.append("C:/Users/.../.qgis/python/plugins")

import sextante
sextante.core.Sextante.Sextante.initialize()
input = "D:/Python_Test/a.shp"
output = "D:/Python_Test/b.shp"

sextante.runalg("qgis:convexhull",input,None,None,output)
print "Finished!"
```

Unfortunately the process fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/.../.qgis/python/plugins\sextante\core\Sextante.py", line 376, in runalg
    alg = Sextante.runAlgorithm(algOrName, None, *args)
  File "C:/Users/.../.qgis/python/plugins\sextante\core\Sextante.py", line 276, in runAlgorithm
    if not param.setValue(args[i]):
  File "C:/Users/.../.qgis/python/plugins\sextante\parameters\ParameterVector.py", line 59, in setValue
    layers = QGisLayers.getVectorLayers(self.shapetype)
  File "C:/Users/.../.qgis/python/plugins\sextante\core\QGisLayers.py", line 79, in getVectorLayers
    layers = QGisLayers.iface.legendInterface().layers()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'legendInterface'
```

What am I doing wrong? Sextante seems to be initialized correctly because

```
sextante.alghelp("qgis:convexhull")
```

gives me

```
ALGORITHM: Convex hull
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    FIELD <ParameterTableField from INPUT>
    METHOD <ParameterSelection>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

I´m using Windows 7 Professional 64Bit and the OsGeo4W installation with QGIS 1.8.0 and python 2.7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer to the following question answers this question as well:

[Access Sextante (processing) in standalone QGIS app?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/access-sextante-processing-in-standalone-qgis-app)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of running QGIS processing algorithms in standalone PyQGIS scripts. Check answers to [Import error for qgis.core when running OSGeo4w shell script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129915/cannot-run-standalone-qgis-script/130304#130304) and [How can I access `processing` with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/how-to-use-qgis-explode-lines-with-python/130337#130337), which provide you with tested examples.